# How to detect event when Select open popup in Ionic2?

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, ionic2

```
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="outletId" (ionChange)="selectDt($event)">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let o of outlets" [value]="o.id" >{{o.outletNameKh}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
```

By this i can detect only after we select the option in the select list.

How can I detect its event when the select popup appears on the screen?

[image]

Comment: Most people can't read this screen shot. Can you provide one in English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `click` event listener to the `ion-select` element.

```
<ion-select (click)="onSelectClicked()" [(ngModel)]="outletId" (ionChange)="selectDt($event)">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let o of outlets" [value]="o.id" >{{o.outletNameKh}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```